# Search - Refine where value is "blank"

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, refiner

I've got a custom search results page and I could do queries with refiners like

```
Title:Banana
```

to refine the results even more. How would I do this then if I'm interested in items where the Title has no value (e.g. is 'blank')

---

I've tried

```
Title:""
```

and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot query on blank or null values. What you need to do is set the value of the target field to a value that indicates it is uninitialized or was previously blank and search for that value.